# Problems with converting string to int

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert a string to a int like this in Unity (thank you Franz Gleichmann for answering twice now i've got new errors) here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("/dev/tty.usbmodem1411", 9600); // set port of your arduino connected to computer
    
    public bool on = false;
    public int speed = 0;
    public string A;
    public string B;

    void Start () {
        sp.Open();
        sp.ReadTimeout = 1;
    }

    void Update () {
        A = sp.ReadLine();
        if (sp.IsOpen) {
            try {
                if (on) {

                    bool isParsable = Int32.TryParse(A, out B);

                    if (isParsable)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(B);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Could not be parsed.");
                    }
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.left + (Time.deltaTime * B / speed));   //error on this line
                    
                }
            } catch (System.Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The aim of this script is to take a number from a USB and move an object by that amount. However, Unity gives me this error:

```
Assets/scripts/Move.cs(37,41): error CS0019: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'float'
```

Any answers will help, if you want you can write your own version of the script. Thanks.

Comment: you are missing a `Using System;`...

Comment: 1. Use `int`, not `Int32`; 2. If you must use names like `Int32`, `using System` is not optional.

Comment: "float to bool" (title) or "string to int" (question)?

Comment: Suggestions: ¹) make sure your title and your question match. ²) thanks for including the complete error messages. However, it would be even better if you pointed out where lines 27 & 37 are in your code, perhaps with a comment like `// <-- first error on this line`

Comment: update after your edit: you declare `B` as `string`... but want to store an `int` in it... it's time to better learn your IDE and what it's trying to tell you.

Comment: In `Int32.TryParse(A, out B);` the variable `B` is expected to be an int not a string (as you have declared it). `B`'s string-i-ness bites you again in the expression `Time.deltaTime * B`. I'm assuming `Time.deltaTime` is a float. You can't multiply a float by a string. Changing the declaration of `B` to an int may fix both problems. Another suggestion: give your variables meaningful names (i.e.  not A & B). That way issues like this are easier to see

Comment: Not related to those two error messages, but a potential error... If `int speed = 0;` and you `(Time.deltaTime * B / speed)` you could be trying to divide with 0. @Flydog57 Your comment is pretty much my answer ;-)

Comment: @cleptus. Yup. Upvoted. I don't think it was there when I started typing my comment. Yours should be the accepted answer

Comment: Not related either but why do you call `sp.ReadLine` before checking `if(sp.IsOpen)` and outside of the `try - catch` ? ^^ Either the first will already have an exception or your entire try catch basically will never catch anyway

Comment: and in general in Unity you want to use `Debug.Log` instead of `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the c# documentation of the [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) function, you will notice the second parameter is of type `Int32`.

Your error:

> CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out string' to 'out int'

Is telling that your `B` variable should be Int32 to be able to store the result of the Int32 data.

```
public string A;
public Int32 B;
```

When you change that `B` variable to a numeric type, your second error `Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'string'` raised at this line would also dissapear.

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.left + (Time.deltaTime * B / speed));
```

Some advice: You should start giving more meaningful names to your variables.

Comment: Just another advice: Don't use `B` if it couldn't be parsed anyway ^^ You probably would want to move that `Translate` line into the `if` case ;)

Answer (score -3):

You must use `int` instead of `Int32`
So your code should look like this

```
bool isParsable = int.TryParse(A, out B);
```

Comment: I've changed it but the same errors appear.

Comment: @Boblet67 Make sure your `B` variable **is not** string.

Comment: That's not the problem. `System.Int32` and `int` are effectively synonyms in C# programs